# USB 3.0...I have a USB 3.0 port on my new laptop, does that mean it will make all USB connections "fast"?

Tags: usb, usb-3

I just bought a new laptop which has a USB 3.0 port.  Does this mean that if I connect to my External Hard Drive via USB, and the external hard drive is older and doesn't have USB 3.0, that I'll still get the speed of USB 3.0 since my computer port is USB 3.0?

Comment: NO! - The USB bus is not the only factor. Many cheap USB 3.1 thumb-drives are no faster than USB2.0 thumb-drives. That is because dirt cheap storage controllers and the cheapest flash-storage available will end up in those cheap and SLOW thumb-drives positioned to catch your eye as you exit stores... USB 3.1 won't magically enchant the slow flash-cells and cheap controllers to perform well enough to saturate the bus... It probably won't affect speed at all with such cheap drives...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - USB 3.0 is backwards compatible and a USB 3.0 port with a USB 2.0 device plugged into it and vice versa would work as a USB 2.0 device at USB 2.0 speeds.

USB 3.0 has an [additional 5 connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Standard-A) to enable the extra speed so a USB 2.0 device will be unable to take advantage of it

Comment: Also note that plugging in USB 2.0 devices won't drop USB 3.0 devices down to USB 2.0 speeds, unlike when you plug in a USB 1.1 device into USB 2.0.

Comment: Assuming you use a hub, or would it drop *everything* on that system down to 1.1 speed?

Comment: It's per controller. Most systems I've seen have two controllers. A hub just extends the controller.